# How does this XSS Payload work?

Tags: xss, iframe

I recently found this payload on a security website. I tested it out and basically it just gave me a blank box. How does it work?

```
<iframe src=j&NewLine;&Tab;a&NewLine;&Tab;&Tab;v&NewLine;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;a&NewLine;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;s&NewLine;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;c&NewLine;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;r&NewLine;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;i&NewLine;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;p&NewLine;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;t&NewLine;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&colon;a&NewLine;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;l&NewLine;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;e&NewLine;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;r&NewLine;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;t&NewLine;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;28&NewLine;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;1&NewLine;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;&Tab;%29></iframe>
```

https://pastebin.com/0R9gzVLa

Comment: care to provide the source of the text so that we understand the context of where you found it?

Comment: did you notice that if you remove all the newlines and tabs that it results in `javascript&colon;alert281%29`? And that's the same as `alert(1)` ? But there are typos so it won't work.

Comment: Can you explain what you did to try and figure this out on your own?

Comment: `<iframe src=javascript:alert281)></iframe>` . This is just part of the payload, and it is missing a `%` for 28 as urlencoded enclosure.

Comment: Questions asking us to analyse random code are off-topic. It can be on-topic if you explain what you *do* understand about the code and specifically what you do not understand.